# How to access custom cell textfield values?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi i have custom cell in tableview.

I have six sections with 1 row. Each row has textfield

How can i access those textfield values in save action

Below my cellForRowAtIndexPath code

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier_result = @"ProfileFieldsCell";

    iPhone_FieldCell = (FieldCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier_result forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(iPhone_FieldCell == nil)
    {
        iPhone_FieldCell = (FieldCell*) [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier_result];
    }

    iPhone_FieldCell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iph-menu-btn.png"]];
    iPhone_FieldCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    iPhone_FieldCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    [iPhone_FieldCell.fieldName setText:[profileItems objectAtIndex:(long)indexPath.section]];
    iPhone_FieldCell.tag = 100+(long)indexPath.section;
    iPhone_FieldCell.fieldValue.delegate = self;

    return iPhone_FieldCell;
```

Comment: Is `fieldName` the textfield you're trying to save?  Is the save action handled by the cell or the controller?

Comment: fieldValue is the textfield, Save action is handled by the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is what it appears to be, somewhere a class exists `FieldCell : UITableViewCell`, then you'd add an instance say call it `FieldCell *cellTitle;` and set that equal to the cell in the data source like so;

```
cellTitle = iPhone_FieldCell;
return iPhone_FieldCell;
```

If there is more than one cell being returned, you'd have to create and if clause to prevent `cellTitle` to be assigned to the wrong cell. And to access this cells text field, you'd simply do:

```
cellTitle.fieldName
```